# Beamer split theme and math mode in subsection title

Tags: beamer

I'm creating a presentation in Beamer which uses the split theme. If I use math mode in a subsection title, then I get error message when compiling the file. The same does not happen for the section titles. A minimal example is given below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{split}

\begin{document}
\section{A title}
\subsection{\texorpdfstring{\(\Delta\geq6\)}{Delta at least 6}}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that you need to run LaTeX twice to produce the error.

Comment: I don't get the error by the above code.

Comment: Strange. I get the following error: `line 10: Bad math environment delimiter. \end{frame}` followed by several more errors. This is the version I'm using: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2014.10.3)

Comment: Texlive 2013 is toooo old. You may have to update.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the version that comes with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Using $ for math mode works (with pdflatex):

`\subsection{\texorpdfstring{$\Delta\geq6$}{Delta at least 6}}`